# A riddle to puzzle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am as stiff and solid as a metal pole
>   
> My head wont drop though I may snap
>   
> But any friction from my hidey-hole
>   
> Will make me flare and lose my head

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You're a match.

I am as stiff and solid as a metal pole

> Admitedly, I can't get this to work. It might refer to the match being a solid object and that a pole is long and thin, like a stick .Or maybe it's a reference to a different use of the word.

My head wont drop though I may snap

> Matches have heads and they are solid objects. But they are soft enough that you can break them in half.

But any friction from my hidey-hole

> Sliding a match against the matchbox, where they are stored (hidey-hole).

Will make me flare and lose my head

> It will ignite and burn up.

Comment: Correct! Sorry about the metal pole bit, I know a match isn't as stiff as a metal pole but it just fitted nicely...

Answer (score 1):

I cant particularly vouch for:

"My head wont drop"

And the last two lines are only so so...

But my first thought was:

> You're a blind rivet?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about a:

> pop rivet (the head stays after the solid pole is snapped)

Comment: Already answered that...  (and please add spoiler tags!)